# Ansible/yaml: If syntax inside the for syntax

Tags: yaml, ansible-template

Is this possible?
I want to decide on which 'dict' for loop will iterate.

```
{% for item, value in {% if source == "cde" %} abc.iteritems() {% else %} def.iteritems() {% endif %} %} item {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see something like:

```
{% for item, value in abc.iteritems() if source == "cde" %}
    {{ item.value }}
{% else %}
    {% for item, value in def.iteritems() %}
        {{ item.value }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```